# ArcGIS Server edit role fails with "Another administrative operation is currently accessing the store"

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, windows-server-2008

I just installed a vanilla instance of ArcGIS Server 10.3.1 on Windows 2008.  From the manager webapp I opened `Security -> Settings`, then configured the server to use:

```
User Store: LDAP
Role Store: LDAP
Authentication Tier:    Web
Authentication Mode:    Web
```

Then I opened `Security -> Roles` and clicked the edit icon next to the role I want to use as administrator.  I get the expected message:

> Role information is being managed externally in your enterprise's LDAP server. As a result, this information cannot be modified in Manager. Only the 'Role Type' attribute, which is managed by ArcGIS Server, can be modified.

I click the radio button to set `Role Type` to `Administrator` and click `Save`.  After working on it for 30 seconds or so, this message is displayed:

> Another administrative operation is currently accessing the store. Please try again later.

I have tried everything I can think of from *trying again later*, to a full uninstall/reinstall of ArcGIS server...  Any suggestions as to what could be causing this?

--- UPDATE ---

I tried following this process on a brand new Windows 2012 VM.  Same problem...  The headache continues...

--- UPDATE 2 ---

I uninstalled everything and this time installed 10.4 following the same instructions.  Now when I try to set the `Role Type`, I get a much more informative error:

```
    Illegal char <|> at index 52: C:\arcgisserver\config-store\/security/roles\global |-| global arcgis administrators.json\
```

It looks like ArcGIS LDAP integration does not support all valid names.  I can't really see a way around this other than:

1. File a report with ESRI
2. Replicate group to another one with a name not including an `|` character.

ARGH!

--- Update 3 ---

For ESRI, the role name is `Global |-| Global ArcGIS Administrators`

Comment: Have your tried bouncing the service, or the server?

Comment: @Vince, I've tried both...  Neither helps.

Comment: I've had race conditions in REST API scripting with Python that were addressed by adding a timing delay, but this appears to be a different issue.  I'd recommend you talk with Tech Support.

Answer (score 3):

While this doesn't help my situation, the answer is, ArcGIS Server does not support all the same characters in Role names as LDAP does.  Hence, having a role with `|` in the name, will cause the edit operation to fail with the *ever-so-useful* error:

> Another administrative operation is currently accessing the store. Please try again later.